# Centre Align featured image after 1st para

Tags: wordpress

I am using this code in wordpress functions.php to display featured image after 1st para.

The problem  is: 
Image is showing left-aligned. 
I want it to be center aligned..

Please modify this code so I can display the image in the centre of post?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_featured_image', 20 );

function insert_featured_image( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single'), $content, 1 );

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace Your code with this.

```
function insert_featured_image( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single', array('class' => 'aligncenter')), $content, 1 ); 
    // You can add Custom class instead of "aligncenter" and give a CSS for Image.
    return $content;
}
```